# Using functions in Laravel macros

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I would like to extend Eloquent Builder to have a support for search function. Inside my service provider I've added the following:

```
Builder::macro('search', function (string $searchBy) {
    ...
}
```

which works. I can now call a search method on my model.

The issue I'm having is that the logic within it is getting a rather complex and I wouldn't like it to be a single large script, however splitting to functions doesn't work since scope when inside a `macro` callback is actually from Eloquent Builder.

So this doesn't work:

```
public function foo()
{
    dd('bar');
}

public function boot()
{
    Builder::macro('search', function (string $searchBy) {
        $this->bla();
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use functions without going over the hassle of extending complete Eloquent Builder?

Comment: Maybe you want to use global scope: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: I do not :) I want to use macros

Comment: How anonymous functions work, your example should work? it shares the scope of where it is defined?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're saying, can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up creating a class which would contain the complete logic I need. I see this as a fairly good OOP practice.

```
Builder::macro('search', function (array $input) {
    $jsonQuery = new JsonQuery($this, $input);
    $jsonQuery->search();

    return $this;
});
```

For anyone interested in details, you can check out [my JSON search package](https://github.com/asseco-voice/laravel-json-search).